# How can I disable an item in a Kendo ListView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, kendo-ui

I'm trying to disable an item in my Kendo listview control.  I've tried calling

```
$('#itemid').prop('disabled', true);
```

but it had no effect (it's a `div`, not an `input`).  I don't want the user to be able to click on this item.  I also tried getting the click event handlers and temporarily setting them aside, thus disabling the control.

```
$('#itemid').data('events')
```

... is supposed to give me the events, but it returns nothing.  How can I disable the item in the listview?

Comment: try $('#itemid').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: @iJay, same result as before.  In both cases, the attribute does not appear on the element in my debugger (using Chrome or Firefox).

Comment: I should add that I've also tried `.attr('disabled', true)`.  The attribute appears on the element, but it is ignored.

Comment: For now my workaround is to store the ID of the current item, and when the item is changed to one that should be disabled, I'm re-selecting the previous item.  It's kind of gimmicky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really supported by Kendo UI at the moment. The selection is cleared in the Selectable's _tap method.
You can hack something together by overriding kendoSelectable's _tap method, e.g.:

```
kendo.ui.Selectable.fn._myTap = kendo.ui.Selectable.fn._tap;
kendo.ui.Selectable.fn._tap =  function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("my-disabled-item")) {
        return;
    }

    this._myTap(e);
}
```

and adding a disableItem method to ListView:

```
kendo.ui.ListView.fn.disableItem =  function(elem) {
    $(elem).addClass("my-disabled-item");
}
```

See a demo which has the first two items disabled here: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/vP2L9/

Note that all of this might break with upgrades (there's no guarantee Telerik will keep this code in the _tap method).