# kendo listBox disable items

Tags: kendo-ui, listbox

I would like to disable some items in the kendo ListBox.
There is a Sample in the kendo docs to disable: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox#methods-enable

But I would like disable some items in the list like:

```html
var data = [
{ 'ProductID':'1', 'ProductName': 'Spalte 1', 'Discontinued': true, 'disabled': true },
{ 'ProductID':'2', 'ProductName': 'Spalte 2', 'Discontinued': true, 'disabled': false},
];
```

My full sample code: http://dojo.telerik.com/iKOmo/10

My goal is, disable items in the listBox when disabled = true is in the data object.

Thanks for some help
Severin

Comment: can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985419/how-can-i-disable-an-item-in-a-kendo-listview

Comment: Thanks for answer, i see this also and tested them. But it doesn't works for the ListBox.

Comment: For those who want to know how to disable all items:

`var listBox = $("#listBox").data("kendoListBox");`
`listBox.enable(".k-item", false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this Problem is:

```js
$("#disable").click(function () {
  //console.log("my object: %o", opt_kendoListBox);       
  //alert(JSON.stringify(opt_kendoListBox.options.dataSource._data));
  for (i = 0; opt_kendoListBox.options.dataSource._data.length > i; i++) {
    if(opt_kendoListBox.options.dataSource._data[i].disabled){
      opt_kendoListBox.enable($(".k-item").eq(i),  false); 
    }
  }
});
```

It works correct only after initialization of listBox.
A sample code: http://dojo.telerik.com/iKOmo/24
Not a perfect solution, but a helping solution i hope so.